# Three-sets Venn diagram using TikZ with comments/labels inside and outside the circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, labels, tikz-styles, venn-diagrams

I am trying to produce a three-sets Venn diagram illustrating my research agenda and my published work. I am having a hard time including the comments inside the circles, particularly regarding the location of the text.

This is what I am looking for: 
[image: Venn Diagram]

Here is my current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[venncircle/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=30em, align=center}, node distance=17em] 
    \node[venncircle] (circle1) {10};    
    \node[venncircle, right of=circle1] (circle2) {6};
    \node (MN) at ($(circle1)!0.5!(circle2)$){9};
    \node[venncircle, below of=MN, yshift=3em] (circle3) {};    
    \node (ML)  at ($(circle1)!0.5!(circle3)$){5};  
    \node (NL)  at ($(circle2)!0.5!(circle3)$){4};   
    \node (MNL)  at ($(MN)!0.3!(circle3)$){2};
    \node (Lleft) [below of=ML, yshift=5em] {16};
    \node (Lright) [below of=NL, yshift=5em] {21};
    \node (outtoprightnum) [above right of=circle2, yshift=4em, xshift=-7em] {\textbf{\textit{\large Comparative Political Institutions}}};
    \node (U)[above left of=circle1, xshift=7em, yshift=4em]    {\textbf{\textit{\large Comparative Political Economy}}};
    \node (M)[above of=circle1, yshift=-4em]{\textbf{}};
    \node (N)[above of=circle2, yshift=-4em]{\textbf{}};
    \node (L)[below right of=circle3, yshift=-4em, xshift=-12em]{\textbf{\textit{\large Political Methodology / Formal     Theory}}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Also, if the name of the article is too big (for example, the title of Article 9 in the above Figure), how could I break the line to fit the entire title of the article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be happy to adjust. I am stuck because the labels appearing in your code and on your desired screen shot differ, and I *think* you want to use those of your code. However, I am not sure, so I stopped at some point.

The main things I did change are

- Switch to positioning syntax (and load the corresponding library). The positioning syntax is e.g. `right=1mm of ...` instead of `right of=...`. This way of positioning is IMHO truly superior to the built-in one.
- Introduce `text width` where appropriate.

Result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[venncircle/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=22em,
 align=center}, node distance=12em] 
    \node[venncircle] (circle1) {Article 10};    
    \node[venncircle, right=-2cm of circle1] (circle2) {Article 6};
    \node (MN) at ($(circle1)!0.5!(circle2)+(0,2em)$){Article 9};
    \node[venncircle, below=3em of MN] (circle3) {Article 7};    
    \node (ML)  at ($(circle1)!0.5!(circle3)$){Article 5};  
    \node (NL)  at ($(circle2)!0.5!(circle3)$){Article 4};   
    \node (MNL)  at ($(MN)!0.35!(circle3)$){Article 2};
    \node (Lleft) at ($(circle3.center)+(-135:7em)$) {Article 16};
    \node (Lright) at ($(circle3.center)+(-45:7em)$) {Article 21};
    \node (outtoprightnum) [above=1mm of circle2,font=\itshape\bfseries\large,text width=4cm] 
     {Comparative Political Institutions};
    \node (U)[above=1mm of circle1,font=\itshape\bfseries\large,text width=4cm]    {Comparative Political Economy};
%     \node (M)[above=1mm of circle1, yshift=-4em]{\textbf{}};
%     \node (N)[above=1mm of circle2, yshift=-4em]{\textbf{}};
    \node (L)[below=1mm of circle3,font=\itshape\bfseries\large,text width=6cm]
     {Political Methodology / Formal Theory};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a black background. How to turn the circles and the text into white at once?

Comment: @Thiago Just add `fill=white` : `venncircle/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=22em, align=center}` -> `venncircle/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=22em, align=center,fill=white}` and the same in the last 3 nodes which have `,text width` : `,text width` -> `,fill=white,text width`.

Comment: Thank you @marmot. I also discovered that adding the following code before `\begin{document}` works: `\usepackage{xcolor}` `\usepackage{pagecolor}` `\pagecolor{black}` `\color{white}`.